# Set border to an image in QListView in Qt

Tags: qt

I am setting a QPixmap to a QStandardItem:

```
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem();
item->setData( pixmap, Qt::DecorationRole );
```

Then I do `appendRow()` and add `item` to the Model.

I display all the pixmaps in the Model in a QListView.
How do I set a thin border to only the 1st item (image) in the ListView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and override it´s [paint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qstyleditemdelegate.html#paint) function. Use this to paint a border to your item. Then set that delegate to your QListView.

Example:

```
void MyDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if(index.row() == 0)
    {
        painter->setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 2));
        painter->drawRect(option.rect.x()+1, option.rect.y(), option.rect.width()-1, option.rect.height());
    }
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

And to [set the delegate for your QListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate):

```
listView->setItemDelegate(new MyDelegate);
```

You don't necessarely have to check the row in the paint function. You can just [set the delegate for a specific row](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForRow):

```
listView->setItemDelegateForRow(0, new MyDelegate);
```